# C#: How to tell a form that other form is closed?

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a form named **frmMain** in which I have the following function:

```
public void openFullScreen(String id,String content)
{
    frmEditor Editor = new frmEditor();
    Editor.WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized;
    Editor.Content = content;
    Editor.ID = id;
    Editor.ShowDialog();
}
```

In Editor.cs I am using following code:

```
private void btnClose_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Object content = browserEditor.Document.InvokeScript("getContent");
    if (content != null)
    {
        object[] args = new object[2];
        args[0] = content.ToString();
        args[1] = _id;
        AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetData("EditorContent", args);
        this.Close();
        //browserEditor.Document.InvokeScript("setEditorContent",args)
    }
}
```

ON closing of **frmEditor** I want to tell **frmMain** that frmEditor is closed now, Upon knowing that I have to display a certain value. How do I check this?

Comment: [ShowDialog](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.showdialog(v=vs.110).aspx) should return something, no? (And it will *block* until said dialog is closed - so just waiting is likely sufficient.)

Comment: I know ShowDialog returns value, on which Event of frmMain do I check this?

Comment: You can only continue the execution if the frmEditor is defintely closed. Otherwise the execution will be stuck in ShowDialog() method. So any code after that will only execute after frmEditor is closed.

Comment: ShowDialog *blocks*, so just "do the stuff" after. `Editor.ShowDialog(); DoOtherStuffWhenTheDialogIsClosed();` - "You can use this method to display a modal dialog box in your application. *When this method is called, the code following it is not executed until after the dialog box is closed* .." (from the previous MSDN link).

Comment: To exchange data you can use public variables in frmEditor to save what you need. Then after ShowDialog method you can access these fields and you know for sure that you are accessing them only after frmEditor is closed, since ShowDialog is a blocking method.

Comment: DialogResult result = Editor.ShowDialog();
 MessageBox.Show(result.ToString()); //always returns Cancel Why?

Comment: Ok now it worked, cna you make it as an answer? Though other replied same too but you answered first!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [ShowDialog](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c7ykbedk.aspx) method blocks until the dialog is closed.

> You can use this method to display a modal dialog box in your application. When this method is called, the code following it is not executed until after the dialog box is closed. The dialog box can be assigned one of the values of the DialogResult enumeration by assigning it to the DialogResult property of a Button on the form or by setting the DialogResult property of the form in code. This value is then returned by this method.

To return a result, you can either set the [DialogResult](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.dialogresult.aspx) property that is built into the `Form`.  If that type doesn't suit your needs, declare a property in `Editor` and retrieve it when `ShowDialog` returns.

```
public partial class Editor : Form
{
    public string YourReturnValue { get; private set; }

    private void btnClose_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // you code here...
        YourReturnValue = "Something you want to return";
    }
 }
```

Then in openForm

```
public void openFullScreen(String id,String content)
{
    frmEditor Editor = new frmEditor();
    Editor.WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized;
    Editor.Content = content;
    Editor.ID = id;
    Editor.ShowDialog( this );
    string retval = Editor.YourReturnValue;
}
```

The important thing to note, is that just because the form is closed, does not mean the object has been destructed.  It is still accessible while the `Editor` variable is in scope.

As an aside, I would recommend [passing an owner into ShowDialog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2005/02/24/379635.aspx).

Answer (score 6):

Just subscribe for `FormClosed` event of Editor instance:

```
private void InitializeChildForm()
{
    var child = new ChildForm();
    child.FormClosed += ChildFormClosed;
    child.ShowDialog();
}

void ChildFormClosed(object sender, FormClosedEventArgs e)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Child form was closed.");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
//you can use DialogResult  object to know to other form is closed
// DialogResult dlgResult = DialogResult.None;

public void openFullScreen(String id,String content)
{
      DialogResult dlgResult = DialogResult.None;  

    frmEditor Editor = new frmEditor();`enter code here`
    Editor.WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized;
    Editor.Content = content;
    Editor.ID = id;
    dlgResult=Editor.ShowDialog();
      if (dlgResult == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
      { 
               // code that you will execute after Editor form is closed
      }

}



private void btnClose_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Object content = browserEditor.Document.InvokeScript("getContent");
    if (content != null)
    {
        object[] args = new object[2];
        args[0] = content.ToString();
        args[1] = _id;
        AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetData("EditorContent", args);

   /* use:  this.DialogResult = System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK;   instead of this.close */
        this.DialogResult = System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK;//this.Close();
        //browserEditor.Document.InvokeScript("setEditorContent",args)
    }
}
```